# Descargar un archivo con angularJS y c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una duda. Necesito saber como descargar un archivo con **angularJS** y **C#** **MVC**. Ya logre guardar el archivo en una ruta aparte, pero a la hora de descargar no sé como recuperarlo. Tengo entendido que es por método `GET`.

Así estoy enviando el archivo:

```
var config = {

  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  },
  transformRequest: function(data) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("jsonData", angular.toJson(data.jsonData));

    for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
    }

    return formData;
  }
};

var datos = {
  jsonData: solicitud,
  files: archivo
};

$http.post('./GuardarSolicitudConArchivo', datos, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descargar un archivo vas a tener que hacer uso del `Blob` de `javascript`

[AngularJS : Download Files by Sending a HTTP Request to Web API](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com.ar/2016/05/angularjs-download-files-by-sending.html)

como veras en el codigo de ejemplo, la magia se da en estas lineas

```
var linkElement = document.createElement('a');

try {

    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
        "view": window,
        "bubbles": true,
        "cancelable": false
    });

    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

el stream que envie el webapi, o action, en el response sera usando por el blob para que despues se pueda forzar la descarga.

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta di solución a mi problema muchisimas gracias,

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una biblioteca de JavaScript llamada [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Solo llama

```
saveAs(archivo, 'NombreArchivo');
```

**Solicitud completa de http:**

```
$http.post('apiUrl', myObject, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  .success(function(data) {
            var archivo= new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            saveAs(archivo, 'NombreArchivo.pdf');
        });
```

> `myObject` es la información POST que está enviando a su API, f.ex. una orden para ser presentada como pdf

**Otro Ejemplo:**

Aquí tiene la solicitud angularjs http a la API que cualquier cliente tendrá que hacer.

```
$http({
    url : '/path/to/your/API',
    method : 'POST',
    params : {},
    headers : {
        'Content-type' : 'application/pdf',
    },
    responseType : 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // TODO when WS success
    var file = new Blob([ data ], {
        type : 'application/csv'
    });
    //trick to download store a file having its URL
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.href        = fileURL; 
    a.target      = '_blank';
    a.download    = 'yourfilename.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

**Explicación del código:**

1. Angularjs solicita un PDF en la URL especificada.
2. El éxito se recibe en la respuesta.
3. Ejecutamos un truco con JavaScript en el front-end:

   - Crea una etiqueta `<a>` html
   - Haga clic en la etiqueta `<a>` del hipervínculo , usando la función `click()` JS

Nota: Para realizar la eliminación del enlace después de que se haya agregado al 
 cuerpo, simplemente reemplace las últimas 2 líneas en su controlador de éxito con esto: `var element = document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild( element );`